# Most elegant way to run parallel tasks on command in python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I am developing a python (2.7) application which takes real time commands and performs tasks (run other modules of the app) on command.

Right now there is only one process which is run like `python run.py`. So, if some task takes little longer, say 20seconds, the application is blocked for those 20 seconds and can't process commands which might come before the process is finished.

I want to launch tasks on command in a way that, they run in parallel and doesn't block the subsequent commands.

What is the most elegant way to do this?

So far I found `subprocess.popen` can be used for scripts. But I want don't want to run the tasks as commands.

Comment: One option is [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) which is distributed task queue

Comment: Why can't you just use threads?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) for this. Once you have set it up, it is very easy to integrate with your application. It will run tasks in the background, limit resource usage if necessary, automatically scale for demand if necessary.